# Track multiple shapes using JavaScript Object Detection

Tags: javascript, shapes, ml5.js, object-tracking

How can I track 2 to 3 objects(shapes: circle, square, triangle, etc.) on a webcam feed using JavaScript?
It needs to be able to tell me the coordinates and sizes of appearing shapes/objects
Is there a pre-trained ml5 model to do it or any teachable machine way?

I am not that familiar with ai/ml so sorry if my question is repetitive or anything.

Comment: Ideally you would train a model to recognise those specific shapes that you want. I'm not sure if you can easily do that with the YOLO / COCOSSD object detectors, but you CAN do it with the FeatureExtractor: https://learn.ml5js.org/#/reference/feature-extractor